# Sum=Integral? Find $m$ so that $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{n^m}{e^{2 \pi n}-1}=\int_0^{\infty } \frac{x^m}{e^{2 \pi x}-1} \, dx$

Tags: sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, special-functions

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3557171/on-proving-that-sum-limits-n-1-infty-fracn13e2-pi-n-1-frac-124/3560431#3560431) asked for a derivation of the interesting relation

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  \frac{n^{13}}{e^{2 \pi n}-1} = \frac{1}{24}$$

In an [attempt to answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4068495/198592) this problem I played around a bit and was surprised that the related integral

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}  \frac{n^{13}}{e^{2 \pi n}-1} \,dn= \frac{1}{24}$$

has the same nice result. Notice that the sum starts at $n=1$ and the integral starts at its "natural" boundary $0$.

Defining more generally

$$S(m) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  \frac{n^m}{e^{2 \pi n}-1}\tag{1a}$$
$$i(m) = \int_{0}^{\infty}  \frac{n^m}{e^{2 \pi n}-1} \,dn\tag{1b}$$

We can ask for which $m$ sum and integral lead to equal values, i.e.

$$S(m) = i(m)\tag{2}$$

It turns out that equality seems to happen if and only if $m=4k+1, k=1,2,3...$.

This picture shows a discrete plot of the quotient $\frac{S(m)}{i(m)}$ of sum and integral.

[image]

**Questions:**

(1) Find all natural solutions $m$ of equation $(2)$

(2) Find an analytic continuation of $S(m)$ to real $m$ and study if the quotient $S(m)/i(m)$ is unity for other values

Hints (for derivations [see](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4068495/198592)):

a) the integral has a closed expression which is not restricted to natural values of $m$

$$i(m)= \frac{1}{(2 \pi )^{m+1} } \zeta (m+1) \Gamma (m+1)\tag{3}$$

Here $\zeta(x)$ is the Riemann zeta function.

b) the sum has a closed expression for $m=1,2,3,...$ as well

$$S(m)=\frac{(-1)^{m+1} \psi _{e^{-2 \pi }}^{(m)}(1)}{(2 \pi )^{m+1}}\tag{4}$$

Here $\psi _{q}^{(m)}(x)$ is the $m$-th derivative of the [$q$-digamma function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PolygammaFunction.html) with respect to x.

EDIT: after a comment of @Jean Marie I saw that Marko Riedel [has derived](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/655547/198592) as a special case of $(4)$ for $m=4k+1$ the simplified formula

$$S(4 k+1)=\frac{B_{4 k+2}}{2 (4 k+2)}, k=1,2,3,...\tag{4a}$$

Here $B_{n}$ is the Bernoulli number.

Comment: Also connected: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/19408

Comment: It is mentionned [here](http://someformulas.blogspot.com/p/functions-for-which-sum-equals-integral.html) (eq. 10) that $s(4k+1)=i(4k+1)$ is a formula due to Glaisher. No precise ref. is given.

Comment: Maybe also of interest: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/170747/1242

Comment: Just fascinating ! One of my claims is that beauty is part of mathematics and vice-versa. Thanks for the link and cheers :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard method is to use that $$\frac{\pi^2}{\sin^2(\pi z)}-\sum_m \frac1{(z+m)^2}=0$$ (it is a $1$-periodic entire function which is bounded on $\Re(z)\in [0,1]$ and which vanishes at $i\infty$)

to get that for $k\ge 4$ even and $\Im(z)>0$ $$G_k(z)=\sum_{(n,m)\ne (0,0)} \frac1{(zn+m)^k}= 2\zeta(k)+\frac{4i\pi}{(k-1)!}\sum_{n\ge 1}\sum_{d\ge 1}(2i\pi d)^{k-1}e^{2i\pi dnz}$$

When $k\equiv 2\bmod 4$ we get that $G_k(i)=0$.

On the other hand $$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{k-1}}{e^{2\pi x}-1}dx=(k-1)!(2\pi)^{-k} \zeta(k),\qquad\sum_{d\ge 1}\frac{d^{k-1}}{e^{2\pi d}-1}=\sum_{d\ge 1}\sum_{n\ge 1}d^{k-1}e^{-2\pi dn}$$

---

The case $k\equiv 0\bmod 4$ has a solution too. From the theory of modular forms (mainly that $E_4(z)^3-E_6(z)^2$ is a non-vanishing cusp form),  with $E_k(z)=\frac{G_k(z)}{2\zeta(k)}$: $$E_k(z)=\sum_{4a+6b=k} c_{k,a,b}E_4(z)^a E_6(z)^b$$ for some rational coefficients $c_{k,a,b}$. As $E_6(i)=0$ we get $$E_k(i) = c_{k,k/4,0}E_4(i)^{k/4}$$ The known closed-form of $E_4(i)$ in term of $\Gamma(1/4)$ implies that $E_k(i)$ is irrational, so it is $\ne 2$ and hence $\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{k-1}}{e^{2\pi x}-1}dx\ne \sum_{d\ge 1}\frac{d^{k-1}}{e^{2\pi d}-1}$.

Comment: Just to check if I have well understood: do you obtain your second formula by successive differentiations of the first one + the fact that the LHS is periodical (with period $1$), therefore identical to its complex Fourier series ?

Comment: Yes, well $\frac{\pi^2}{\sin^2(\pi z)}$ is the derivative of $\frac{2i\pi}{e^{-2i\pi z}-1}=2i\pi \sum_{d\ge 1} e^{2i\pi d z}$ then differentiate the latter $k-1$ times

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: @ reuns Thank you for your answer which excells in your "notorious" brevity. But, honestly, I would greatly appreciate a word or two more in your so that I can follow your arguments. And what about non-integer $m$?

Comment: Which step is unclear to you? I am treating only the case $k\equiv 2\bmod 4$. @Dr.WolfgangHintze

Comment: @ reuns Which step is unclear to me? I would say it is the zeroeth step: I don't see the plan of the proof starting from a l.h.s. (integral) then doing operations that are clearly motivated and ending up at the r.h.s. (sum) or the other way round. Also it would facilitate things if the variable names and definitions (e.g. i(m), S(m)) follow those of the question. I can derive and prove parts of the puzzle but I can't put them together. I am sure that I could learn very much from your "stenographic" answers but it takes me too long to find the "entry point". 1+ and sorry to bother you :-(

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze I cannot guess what you don't understand, so... The two identities in "on the other hand" are trivial, right? And they appear at the previous equation, right? So $G_k(i)=0$ solves the case $k\equiv 2\bmod 4$, right? Well $G_k(z)$ has two expressions, one making it obvious that for $k\equiv 2\bmod 4$, $G_k(i)=0$, the other (which follows from the pole expansion of $\pi^2/\sin^2(\pi z)$ which follows from that bounded entire functions are constant) making your series and integral appear for $z=i$.

Answer (score 4):

Acknowledgement: This solution was initiated by my ambition to understand the "stenographic" answer of [@reuns](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4071278/198592). I would not have come to terms without the challenges and nudges of his answer.

I have tried to make the solution as simple as possible, in particular I have made no reference to special functions, and the only non-elementary ingredient is the partial fraction decomposition of the cotangent.

We have to find the values of $k$ for which

$$S(k) := \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^{k-1}}{e^{2 \pi n}-1}=i(k) :=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{n^{k-1}}{e^{2 \pi n}-1}\,dn  \tag{1}$$

The integral easily calculated with the result

$$i(k) = \frac{(k-1)!}{(2\pi)^{k-1}}\zeta(k)\tag{2} $$

The tough part is the sum. Instead of the original sum with the power on $n$ we consider the expression

$$g(k,t) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{2\pi n t}}{e^{2 \pi n}-1}\tag{3}$$

from which the sum in question can be generated by differentiating thus

$$S(k) = (-\frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{\partial}{\partial t})^{k-1}g(k,t) |_{t\to 0}\tag{4}$$

Now we carry out some transformations on $g(k,t)$

$$\begin{align}
g(k,t)
&=\sum_{m=1} ^{\infty}\frac{1}{e^{2\pi(m+t)}-1}\tag a\\
&=\frac{1}{2} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\left( \coth\left(\pi(m+t)\right)-1 \right) \tag b\\
&=\frac{1}{2} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{i}{\pi}   \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\left( \frac{1}{i(m+t)+n} \right)-1 \right)\tag c\\
&=\frac{1}{2} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\left( \frac{i}{\pi} \frac{1}{i(m+t)}\\
+ \frac{i}{\pi}\sum_{n \ge 1}\left( \frac{1}{i(m+t)+n}+\frac{1}{i(m+t)-n} \right)-1 \right)\tag d\\
\end{align}
$$

Explanation:
$(a)$: $\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{e^{- 2\pi t n}}{e^{2 \pi n}-1}= \sum_{n\ge 1}e^{-2 \pi n t}\sum_{m\ge 1} e^{-2 \pi n m}=\sum_{m\ge 1}\left(\sum_{n\ge 1}e^{-2 \pi n t} e^{-2 \pi n m}\right)$

$(b)$: $\frac{1}{e^{2a}-1}=\frac{e^{-a}}{e^{a}-e^{-a}}+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}=\frac{e^{-a}}{e^{a}-e^{-a}}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{e^{a}-e^{-a}}{e^{a}-e^{-a}} -\frac{1}{2} = \frac{e^{-a}+\frac{1}{2}(e^{a}-e^{-a})}{e^{a}-e^{-a}}-\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2}\left( \frac{e^{a}+e^{-a}}{e^{a}-e^{-a}} -1 \right)$

$(c)$: We use the well-known partial fraction decomposition of the cotangent $\cot(\pi z) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n+z)}$ and switch to an imaginary argument: $\cot(i \pi x) = i \coth(\pi x)$

$(d)$: We split the two-sided sum into three parts: $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} c(n) =\sum_{n=0}^{0} c(n)+\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1} c(n)+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c(n)= c(0) + \sum_{n \ge 1}\left(  c(n)+ c(-n) \right)$ so that all indices are in the poistive range.

Hence we find from $(4)$ with $(c)$

$$S(k) = \frac{(k-1)!}{(2\pi)^k}\left(\zeta(k) + W(k)   \right)\tag{5}$$

where

$$W(k) = \sum_{n,m \ge 1}\left( \frac{1}{(m-i n)^k} + \frac{1}{(m+i n)^k} \right)\tag{6}$$

Comparing $(2)$ and $(5)$ shows that equality $(1)$ holds if

$$W(k) = 0\tag{7}$$

We can easily find a necessary condition by the following symmetry argument:
as the summation is symmetric against the interchange of $n$ and $m$ the sum vanishes if the summand

$$a(n,m) =  \frac{1}{(m-i n)^k} + \frac{1}{(m+i n)^k} \tag{8}$$

is antisymmetric.

Starting with the summand $(8)$ in reverse order we have

$$\begin{align}
a(m,n) &= \frac{1}{(n-i m)^k} + \frac{1}{(n+i m)^k}\\
&=\frac{(i)^{k}}{(m+i n)^k} + \frac{(-i)^k}{(m-i n)^k}\\
&=
i^{k}\left((-1)^k \frac{1}{(m-i n)^k}+\frac{1}{(m+i n)^k} \right)\end{align}\tag{9}$$

In order that this is the negative of $(8)$ we need first $k = 2 p$ and then $i^{2p} = -1$ which requires odd $p$ so that we obtain finally

$$k = 2 (2q+1), \text{or } k \equiv 2 \text{ }(\bmod 4 )\tag{10}$$

Notice the argument breaks down for $k=2$ since the sum $W(k)$ is not konvergent. And, indeed, there is no equality of sum and integral in this case but for $k=2$ we have $i(2) = \frac{1}{24}$ and $S(k) = \frac{1}{24}-\frac{1}{8 \pi}$

The first few coinciding integrals (= sums) are in the format (k,S(k))

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 6 & \frac{1}{504} \\
 10 & \frac{1}{264} \\
 14 & \frac{1}{24} \\
 18 & \frac{43867}{28728} \\
 22 & \frac{77683}{552} \\
 26 & \frac{657931}{24} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Alternative closed form of $S(k)$**

An alternative closed form expression of the sum $S(k)$ in terms of known functions was given in $(4)$ of the OP. We provide here the missing derivation:

We consider again the generating function (slightly different from the above developments) which can be transformed as follows (notice that $m=k-1$)

$$\begin{align} & \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{e^{n t}}{e^{2 \pi  n}-1}\\
= & \sum _{j=1}^{\infty } \left(\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } e^{n t} \exp (2 \pi  (-j) n)\right)\\
=& \sum _{j=1}^{\infty } \frac{1}{e^{2 \pi  j-t}-1}=\sum _{j=1}^{\infty } \frac{e^t}{e^{2 \pi  j}-e^t}\\
= &\frac{-\psi _{e^{-2 \pi }}^{(0)}\left(1-\frac{t}{2 \pi }\right)-\log \left(1-e^{-2 \pi }\right)}{2 \pi }
\end{align}\tag{11}$$

The last equality was found using Mathematica (which refused to do the sum the step before).

Now the $m$-th derivative at $t=0$ gives $(4)$ of the OP.

Notice that $(11)$ also provides the case $m=0$ ($k=1$).

Things are even simpler! As a matter of fact our sum is not only expressible in terms of the q-polygamma function, it is essentially **defining** it.

Indeed, the [q-digamma function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PolygammaFunction.html) is defined as

$$\psi_{q}(z)=\log (q) \sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{q^{n+z}}{1-q^{n+z}}-\log (1-q)\tag{12}$$

Letting

$$q\to e^{-2 \pi }\tag{13}$$

$(12)$ becomes

$$\psi_{q}(z)=-2 \pi  \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{1}{e^{2 \pi  (n+z-1)}-1}-\log \left(1-e^{-2 \pi }\right)\tag{14}$$

Notice that we have shifted the summation index $n\to n-1$ which is adjusted by taking $z \to z-1$.

Comparison with $(11)$ shows agreement.