# Is there a closed form of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{n} } {e^{2 \pi n}-1}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, special-functions

Recently there were some discussions [[1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1943244/198592)], [[2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3557171/198592)], [[3](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4070922/198592)] of sums of the type

$$S(k) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^{k-1}}{e^{2 \pi n}-1}\tag{1}$$

Here $k$ was assumed to be a positive integer.

For a positive integer $k$ I have given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3557171/198592) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4070922/198592) a closed expression with a slightly different definition of $S(m)$.

Now I would like to drop this restriction an allow $k$ to assume real values.

**Questions**

(1) as a typical example: is there a closed expression for $S(\frac{3}{2})$?

(2) what are the analytic properties of $S(z)$ in the complex $z$-plane?

**My attempts regarding question (1)**

It is more convenient to study the "generating" sum

$$S(z,t) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^{z-1} e^{-n t}}{e^{2 \pi n}-1}\tag{2}$$

so that $S(z) = S(z,t=0)$ and also

$$S(z+1,t) = - \frac{\partial S(z,t)}{\partial t}\tag{3}$$

I now replace the power of $n$ by an integral

$$n^{z-1} = \frac{1}{\Gamma(1-z)} \int_{0}^{\infty} s^{-z} e^{-n s} \tag{4}$$

which leads to an integral representation as follows

$$S(z,t)=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{e^{-n t} n^{z-1}}{e^{2 \pi  n}-1}=\frac{1}{\Gamma (1-z)} \int_0^{\infty } s^{-z} f(s,t) \, ds, \Re(z)<1 \tag{5}$$

where

$$\begin{align}
f(s,t)  & = \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{e^{ - n (s+t)}}{e^{2 \pi  n}-1}\\
 & =\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \sum _{m=1}^{\infty } e ^{ -n (s+t)-2 \pi  n m}\\
&  = \sum _{m=1}^{\infty } \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } e^{ -n(2 \pi  m + s+t)}\\
& =\sum _{m=1}^{\infty } \frac{1}{e^{2 \pi  m+s+t}-1}\\
& =-\frac{\psi _{e^{-2 \pi }}^{(0)}\left(\frac{s+t}{2 \pi }+1\right)+\log \left(1-e^{-2 \pi }\right)}{2 \pi }
\end{align}\tag{6}$$

Inserting this into $(5)$ we obtain

$$\begin{align}
S(z,t) & =\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{e^{-n t} n^{z-1}}{e^{2 \pi  n}-1}\\
& =\frac{-1}{2 \pi\Gamma (1-z)} \int_0^{\infty } s^{-z} \left(\psi _{e^{-2 \pi }}^{(0)}\left(\frac{s+t}{2 \pi }+1\right)+\log \left(1-e^{-2 \pi }\right)\right) \, ds, \Re(z)<1 \end{align}\tag{7}$$

where $\psi _{q }^{(0)}\left(x\right)$ is the [q-polygamma function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PolygammaFunction.html).

Now we can calculate the sum in question as

$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{\sqrt{n}}{e^{2 \pi  n}-1}
=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\left(\frac{1}{2 \pi }\right)^2  \int_0^{\infty } \frac{1}{\sqrt{s}} \psi _{e^{-2 \pi }}^{(1)}\left(\frac{s}{2 \pi }+1\right) \, ds\tag{8}$$

here we have used

$$S\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)=-\frac{\partial }{\partial t}S\left(\frac{1}{2},t\right)|_{t\to 0}\tag{9}$$

and

$$\frac{\partial }{\partial t}\psi _{e^{-2 \pi }}^{(0)}\left(\frac{s+t}{2 \pi }+1\right)=\frac{1}{2 \pi } \psi _{e^{-2 \pi }}^{(1)}\left(\frac{s+t}{2 \pi }+1\right)\tag{10}$$

Here I am stuck, as I'm not sure if $(8)$ can be further simplified. The analytic properties should be deducible from $(7)$.

Comment: Dear downvoter in the dark, I'd appreciate to see a reason. Thank you.